# Buck regulators and led

Tags: led

I am very new to LED technology and still finding my way around voltages, strings and amps. My question is regarding "buck regulator", I've been told that they can be used as stand alone power supply's, is this true?. I already have a driver but it runs at 1.5A, whilst my chip requires only 1amp max, so would a buck regulator help to control the amperage?.

Comment: How can you possibly expect a positive answer without specifying the chip you are using and the current power supply arrangement it requires. BTW a stand alone power supply needs a source of energy and a buck regulator doesn't inherently have a source of meaningful energy.

Comment: Stand alone power supply, please specify the reason using standalone here, its confusing.

Answer (score 2):

There are literally thousands of different LED driver solutions today. Most are either DC-DC boost, buck or line isolated AC-DC, constant current, (fixed, or dimmable).  power Factor Corrected (PFC) on AC (or not)

The latest trend is direct [**offline**](http://www.fujitsu.com/sg/news/pr/fmal_20121210.html) AC-DC without isolation for protected lamp solutions only.

These come with all the above extra features for low incremental cost.
The value of using more expensive portable AC PSU's to be modified for LED's or custom external drivers must compete with the great advantage of offline flyback dimmable, PFC solutions or require the transformer isolation for human handling with >=3kV isolation.

Answer (score 0):

A Buck Regulator is a type of Switching Regulator designed to efficiently lower a higher voltage to a lower voltage. It is normally used as a Voltage Source, where the output is kept at a constant Voltage while allowing the current to vary. Most standard Buck Regulators are not used as a Current source, but they can be. Some small variations on the wiring and parts will let a Buck regulator work as a Current Source, instead of requiring a dedicated LED Driver.

[Here is an app note from Analog on how to convert a standard Buck Regulator into a LED Driver.](http://www.analog.com/library/analogdialogue/archives/47-03/smart_led_driver.html) The only difference for a *simple* current mode is changing R2 for the LED in question. Note, that R1 will be dissipating `0.6V * 1A = 0.6W` so it will need to be a 1W resistor. The app note has more efficient designs as well. It's a great read.

> In operation, a divided down copy of the output voltage is connected to the FB pin, compared with an internal 600-mV reference, and used to generate the proper duty cycle to the switches. In the steady state, the FB pin is held at exactly 600 mV, so VOUT is regulated at 600 mV times the division ratio. If the upper resistor is replaced by LEDs (Figure 5), the output voltage must be whatever is needed (within ratings) to maintain 600 mV at FB; therefore, the current through the LEDs will be controlled at 600 mV/RSENSE.

Voltage Regulator Mode:
[image]

Simple/Inefficient Current Regulator Mode:
[image]

**As a note, most LED drivers are internally switching regulators with extra hardware for pwm or digital control. The only difference between a Buck Regulator and a LED driver is the intended application.**